# Why do I not see slow start in this TCP packet capture?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I am looking at the packet flow between a server and a client (which is downloading a file from the server). As you can see in the packet capture below (with IP addresses omitted), after the initial three-way handshake, a GET request is made for a file. However, I don't see a "slow-start" phase in this flow; all 10 or so packets required to transmit the file contents are sent in one go, and the transaction is then over. Why do we not see the typical (1 packet, 2 packets, 4 packets, etc.) in this scenario? Both machines involved in this transaction are using a vanilla Linux system (more information can be provided if required). I am sure it is part of some TCP or HTTP optimization or negotiation, but I want to clarify this.

```
    1   0.000000  TCP 76 42044 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=2648786025 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2   0.000025  TCP 76 80 → 42044 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=26847 Len=0 MSS=8961 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3730157118 TSecr=2648786025 WS=512
    3   0.001033  TCP 68 42044 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=2648786027 TSecr=3730157118
    4   0.001167  HTTP 154 GET /file HTTP/1.1 
    5   0.001183  TCP 68 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=0 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027
    6   0.001407  TCP 1516 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    7   0.001409  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=1449 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    8   0.001410  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=2897 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    9   0.001411  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=4345 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   10   0.001412  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=5793 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   11   0.001420  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=7241 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   12   0.001421  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=8689 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   13   0.001422  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=10137 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   14   0.001423  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=11585 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   15   0.001424  TCP 1516 80 → 42044 [ACK] Seq=13033 Ack=87 Win=27136 Len=1448 TSval=3730157119 TSecr=2648786027 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
   16   0.002196  TCP 68 42044 → 80 [ACK] Seq=87 Ack=5793 Win=40832 Len=0 TSval=2648786028 TSecr=3730157119
```

Comment: The initial TCP window is larger than the total data sent. Remember that protocols above OSI layer-4 (e.g. HTTP) and host/server configurations are off-topic here.

Comment: Right, my question was regarding congestion control, so I believed that was relevant here (host/server configurations were just a by-product, in case it would help someone mention why a certain TCP-IP stack implementation was behaving how it is). So is the initial TCP window not initially the MSS? That was my understanding.

Comment: No the MSS and the window are two different things. The MSS is how much data can be sent in a single segment. Each side will announce its window to the other side, and those can be different values. Your capture shows the MSS and windows. Notice that they are different values. [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793) is the definition of TCP, and it explains how that works.

Comment: I'm aware of the difference, what I thought though, was the window was INITIALLY the value of the MSS, in the start of slow start. I will check out RFC 793, but is my statement inaccurate/not always true?

Comment: No, those are two completely separate things. I'm not sure why you got that idea.

Comment: Came across this post: https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary-cwnd-and-rwnd/


`Congestion window with an initial value of one maximum segment size (MSS) and`

Comment: That is a demonstration of a particular scenario: "_In this scenario..._"

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin, I was misunderstanding it. Looks like on linux specifically, a default value could be 10 segments worth.